# Prove that $\mu(B\setminus A)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a problem:

Suppose $m$ is a measure on algebra $\mathcal{C}$. Then

$$\mu^*(A)= \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty m(P_i)\mid A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}P_i, P_i\in\mathcal{C}\right\}$$ is outer measure and $\mu^*(A)= m(A)$ if $A\in \mathcal{C}$.

We use Carathedory's Theorem to create a measure $\mu$ on $\sigma$- algebra $\mathcal{L}\supset\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{C})\supset\mathcal{C}.$ Assume $A \in\mathcal{C}$ and use the definition, we find for any $k=1,2,...,\mathcal{P}_{ik}\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}P_{ik}$
and $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}m(P_{ik})\le \mu^*(A)+1/k=\mu(A)+1/k.$

Let $B= \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}P_{ik}$, we have $A\subset{B}, B\in\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{C})$ and $\mu(B)\le\mu(A)$.

Since $A\subset{B}$, thus $\mu(B)=\mu(A)$.

I want to show that $\mu(B\setminus A)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your deduction is invalid when $\mu(A)=+\infty$ and when $\mu(A)<+\infty$ 
we have
$$\mu(B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B\setminus A)$$
to obtain 
$$\mu(B\setminus A)=0.$$